# How to make Service application run once a year on a Specific date?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, service

I want to make the C# windows service application run only once a year instead of Daily

This has to happen every year on the same date and same time.
For example: 
the Date has to be `March 31` and the time should be `23:59`
I'm trying to do this from `App.config` file

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key ="Mode" value ="YEARLY"/>
    <!-- <add key ="Mode" value ="Interval"/>-->
    <add key ="IntervalMinutes" value ="1"/>
    <add key ="ScheduledTime" value ="23:59:00"/>
    <add key = "ScheduledDate" value =""/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I want to make it happen on the above mentioned date and time. How can I get this done? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Console application + Scheduled tasks seems a better way of doing this.

Comment: you should use [Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page)

Comment: Some dates and times can occur more than once in a year (due to daylight savings). What should happen for those scenarios?

Comment: @mjwills Not in my time zone, we don't have daylight savings

Comment: What happens if it is scheduled for 4am, and the PC is shutdown between 1am and 6am?

Comment: @mjwills any thing can happen but those are ridiculous w.r.t the question

Comment: @mjwills thats not going to happen as it would be running on a server machine.

Comment: I strongly disagree @Rahul. The OP wants to run it **once a year**. I am suggesting he / she think through the edge cases. There are hundreds of ways to solve this - but knowing the right solution depends partly on knowing what should happen in edge cases (should it run at 6am since it is key that it runs, or should it not - since it was critical that it ran at **exactly** 4am). The OP says it is running on a server machine. That doesn't help, really. Since server machines crash, or AWS kills them, or they need to be updated with Windows Update. Or they suffer power outages.

Comment: If its your server another option is to set a reminder in your cell phones calendar & run it manually.  I would always feel the need to check a yearly task executed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a service which has a timer, every x seconds it checks to see if the current time + x seconds is greater than the target time. Once this magical moment has been triggered, do that thing you wanted to do, then the service goes back to 'checking the time' for another 365 days.

Obviously a scheduled task would be a more sensible solution, but sensibility isn't always compatible with out requirements :)